# Why do the following comparisons give different results?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to compare the following two quantities: an integer 'i' and the size of a vector v.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> v(26,0);
    int i = -1;

    cout << i << " " << v.size() << endl;
    if (i < v.size()) cout << "a1" << endl;
    else cout << "b1" << endl;

    if (-1 < 26) cout << "a2" << endl;
    else cout << "b2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the following code, the output that I get is:
-1 26
b1
a2

whereas I expect it to give:
-1 26
a1
a2

Why is this happening?

Comment: When comparing signed to unsigned the compiler converts the signed value to unsigned. That's why you see what you see. The unsigned version of `-1` is just the biggest unsigned integer.

Comment: Is your compiler warning you about comparing a signed value to an unsigned value? If no, you need a better C++ compiler. If yes, don't ignore your compiler's warning messages. There's always a reason for them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, the compiler didn't give me any warnings.

Comment: `gcc`, with the `-Wall` option (after all, all experienced C++ developers automatically enable all compiler warnings), definitely gives a warnings message.

Comment: `-Wall` is not "all compiler warnings". It is more like `-Wsome`. I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two arguments for `i < v.size()` are `int` (which is signed) and `size_t` (which is unsigned). In this case C++ rules say that the signed quantity is converted to unsigned first. So `-1` is converted to an unsigned quantity. This is done by adding the unsigned range to the number in question. In the case of `-1` this results in the largest possible unsigned quantity, which is bigger than whatever `v.size()` is so that comaprison is false.

I'm sure you know why `-1 < 26` is true.

Try not to mix signed and unsigned types when comparing integers. It can lead to surprises. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen OK I'll clarify, the complete rules are very complex though.

Comment: Still not guaranteed to be true (think 32 bit `size_t` and 64 `int`), but good enough for this audience probably.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ooh, I see you won! Glad my vote helped ^_^ Grats.